# How to programmatic render JSP files?

Tags: jsp, web-applications, modularization

Currently, I'm using Velocity instead of JSP, for its flexibility. For some reasons, I need to distribute my web modules in `jar` archive, rather than `war` archive`.

I have read the servlet specification, though, but I didn't find a way to programmatic invoke the jasper engine.

My idea is, split web application to several modules:

- one top-level `war` module, which contains `web.xml`, and all 3rd-party jar dependencies.
- other `jar` modules contains http servlets (`jsp` is a special form of servlet).

It's very easy to embed Velocity templates in class resources, so I'm wondering if I can do the same job with JSP?

**EDIT**

The problem of Velocity is, we have to use some taglibs, JSF, etc. to create a rich web UI, which can't be done by Velocity templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *we have to use some taglibs, JSF, etc. to create a rich web UI, which can't be done by Velocity templates.*

Use [Facelets](http://facelets.java.net/) instead of JSP. It not only offers better templating possibilities than JSP, but it is also possible to serve Facelet files straight from classpath. Assuming that you're still on JSF 1.x (because JSF 2.x uses *by default* Facelets instead of JSP and there is really no reason to prefer JSP over Facelets), then you can enable serving Facelets from JAR as follows:

```
import com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultResourceResolver;

public class CustomResourceResolver extends DefaultResourceResolver {

    @Override
    public URL resolveUrl(String resource) {
        URL url = super.resolveUrl(resource);

        if (url == null) {
            if (resource.startsWith("/")) {
                resource = resource.substring(1);
            }

            url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resource);
        }

        return url;
    }

}
```

which you register as follows in `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.RESOURCE_RESOLVER</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.CustomResourceResolver</param-value>
</context-param>
```

To learn more about Facelets, start with this excellent [developer documentation](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html).

Comment: CustomResourceResolver doesn't work as expect, though. In Myfaces-impl, it only resolves the root resource ('/'), and then cached the root URL, and then just join other resources with the cached URL. i.e., if resources are in different jars, things broken.

Comment: Fortunately I've patched on myfaces-impl, though this made our program tight coupled with myfaces-impl.